# Play Again Function Not Working

Tags: python

The quiz won't break when n or no is entered, it will just loop the quiz again as it would do when y or yes is entered.(The code for this yes_No function is at the bottom) I just need help with the code thank you 
The quiz won't break when n or no is entered, it will just loop the quiz again as it would do when y or yes is entered.(The code for this yes_No function is at the bottom) I just need help with the code thank you

```
score = 0

def strchecker(question):
    valid=False
    while not valid:
        user_Name = input(question)
        if user_Name!="":
            valid=True
            return user_Name
        else:
            print("Please do not leave username blank")

print("*************Welcome to the Te Reo Maori Quiz***************\n"
       "You will be give a series of 6 questions,\nto answer you will enter an answer between 1 and 4.\n\nBest of Luck,and remember if you would like to quit the game just press enter :)\n")

user_Name = strchecker("Please enter your username:\n")

print("Hi", user_Name,"Here is your first question:\n")

keep_going=""
while keep_going=="":

#  List of questions in Quiz
    question_List = ["How do you write number 1 in Maori?\n1.Tekau 2.Tahi 3.Ono 4.Rua",
                      "What is does tahi + tahi = ?\n1.Rua 2.Rimu 3.Ono 4.Tahi",
                      "How do you write blue in Maori?\n1.Kakariki 2.Kikorangi 3.Whero 4.Ma",
                      "What two colours make blue?\n1.Ma + Whero 2.Kikorangi + Kowhai 3.Whero + Pararui 4.Ma + Mangu",
                      "Who was the god of the forest and birds?\n1.Ranginui 2.Paptuanuku 3.Tane-Mahuta 4.Tangaroa",
                      "Who were Tane Mahutas Parents?\n1.Tangaroa + Ranguinui 2.Punga + Ranganui 3.Tangaroa + Rongo 4.Papatunuku + Ranganui"]

    # List of Correct Answers
    correct_Answer = [2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]


    # If user enters anything that is not an integer between 1 and 4 it will be an invalid input 
    def intcheck(question, low, high):
        valid= False
        while not valid:
            error= "Whoops! Please enter an integer between {} and {}\n".format(low, high)
            try:
                response = int(input("Please enter your answer or press enter to quit\n"))

                if low <= response <= high: 
                    return response
                else:
                    print(error)
                    print()
            except ValueError:
                  print(error)


    # Get a question from the question list and print and loop one by one 
    for idx, question in enumerate(question_List):
        print(question)

        Answer = intcheck("Please enter in an answer or press enter to quit", 1,4)
        print()
    # Get answer and check if it is correct or incorrect by going to the list of correct answers 
        if Answer == correct_Answer[idx]:
                print("Well Done, your answer was correct\n")
                score +=1
        else:
             print("Hard Luck, your answer was incorrect\n")

    if score <4:
        print("************************************************************")
        print("You got",score,"out of 6.\n\nYou should get more than 3/6, try the quiz again to improve your knowledge.\n\n")
    elif score >4 or score<7:
        print("*************************************************************")
        print("You got",score,"out of 6.\n\nNice job! Your study payed off!\n\n")

    def strchecker(question):
        valid=False
        while not valid:
            response=input(question)
            if response.lower()=="yes" or response.lower()=="y":
                response="yes"
                valid=True
                return response
                keep_going

            elif response.lower()=="no" or response.lower()=="n":
                response="no"
                valid=True
                return response
                print(" Thank you for playing. You have chose to quit the game")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input, please enter yes or no\n\n")

    yes_No = strchecker("Would you like to play again\n")
```

Comment: Don't you realise that code after a `return` will not be executed?

Comment: No sorry I am 12 just learning

Comment: Don't take comments too hard, we all have to start somewhere.  `return` exits the current function, so code after the `return` in that function will be ignored.  For example:  `return response;
                print(" Thank you ...");
                break` - the `print` and the `break` are ignored.  Also you have: `return response;
                keep_going`, the `keep_going` is useless for two reasons, one is that it is after the `return`, but another is that this is a string, you are not setting it to anything.

Comment: Don't comment "doesn't work" - that's what dumb users say, not IT practitioners like you and me.  Say *exactly* what happens, you have to help us help you.

Comment: Okay so then what do I do, doesn't work means the code just loops again when I enter no just as I explained at the top?

Comment: Describe the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
def strchecker(question):
        valid=False
        while not valid:
            response=input(question)
            if response.lower()=="yes" or response.lower()=="y":
                response="yes"
                valid=True # will not loop, useless here
                keep_going
                return response # return yes
            elif response.lower()=="no" or response.lower()=="n":
                response="no"
                valid=True # will not loop, useless here
                print(" Thank you for playing. You have chose to quit the game")
                return response #return no
            else:
                print("Invalid input, please enter yes or no\n\n")
```

You have to know that when a function reaches a `return` statement it ends. So, for example, if you print something AFTER your return statement, it'll never be printed

Comment: sorry? so what do I have to do?

Comment: Thank you:) That printed the You have chose to quit the game statement but didn't "break" the code

Comment: Please help, it works just it doesn't work but the print statement works

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Many things wrong with this script.First, I feel like the first strchecker() func. has no justifiable reason to exist since its used only once properly. Second, you don't need to assign a variable just to make a loop go endlessly until a condition is met(This is what was most lacking in your script).

Introducing: The While True syntax:

```
while True:
    do stuff
    if stuff == stuff i wanted:
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Now here else pass means just go to the top of the loop and continue, this is usually implied and you don't need to write else pass part explicitly in a while True loop.

Here is a modified version of your script that uses this concept I've replaced most things I thought were inefficient and changed the dynamic of the code but the essence is still there i believe.

Notes: variable **c** is a counter, variable **inp** stands for input and stores the final yes/no input, score is calculated but simply printed out instead of str manipulation and formatting(I'm sure you can do this yourself), Some changes are present just to make it easier to follow PEP8 standards (ex: Splitting questionsList into questionsList and option_list).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def checker(query):
    while True:
        user_in = input(query)
        if user_in == "":
            end = True
            return end
        elif user_in in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '']:
            return user_in
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")


def main():
    score = 0
    print("*************Welcome to the Te Reo Maori Quiz***************\n",
          "You will be give a series of 6 questions,\n",
          "to answer you will enter an answer between 1 and 4.\n",
          "\nBest of Luck,and remember if you would like to quit the game ",
          "just press enter :)\n")

    while True:
        user_name = input("Please enter your username:\n")
        if user_name == "":
            print("Please do not leave username blank")
        else:
            print("Hi {}, here is your first question:\n".format(user_name))
            break
    question_List = ["How do you write number 1 in Maori?",
                     "What is does tahi + tahi = ?",
                     "How do you write blue in Maori?",
                     "What two colours make blue?",
                     "Who was the god of the forest and birds?",
                     "Who were Tane Mahutas Parents?"]

    options_list = ["1.Tekau 2.Tahi 3.Ono 4.Rua",
                    "1.Rua 2.Rimu 3.Ono 4.Tahi",
                    "1.Kakariki 2.Kikorangi 3.Whero 4.Ma",
                    "1.Ma + Whero 2.Kikorangi + Kowhai 3.Whero + Pararui 4.Ma + Mangu",
                    "1.Ranginui 2.Paptuanuku 3.Tane-Mahuta 4.Tangaroa",
                    "1.Tangaroa + Ranguinui 2.Punga + Ranganui 3.Tangaroa + Rongo 4.Papatunuku + Ranganui"]
    correct_Answer = [2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

    c = 0
    while c <= 5:
        print("{}\n{}".format(question_List[c], options_list[c]))
        ans = checker("Please enter in an answer or press enter to quit\n")
        if ans is True:
            break
        else:
            if ans == str(correct_Answer[c]):
                print("Well Done, your answer was correct\n")
                score += 1
                c += 1
            else:
                print("Hard Luck, your answer was incorrect\n")
                c += 1
    print(score)


while True:
    main()
    while True:
        inp = input("Would you like to play again\n")
        inp = inp.lower()
        if inp in ['yes', 'no']:
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid Input')
    if inp == 'no':
        break
    elif inp == 'yes':
        pass
```

Comment: Cool whatever works lol. Though it's a really minor thing, try to write cleaner code.